# Screenshots are not generating for failure cases using robot framework if i am doing execution through Jenkins in Linux slave

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

In Robot framework by default screenshots are generating for failure cases.I tried using **Get page screenshot** keyword, but still i can't see screenshots. Using the same script i can see screenshots if i am doing the execution in local machine.

I am executing with headless chrome in Linux slave with Jenkins. Same scripts are working in local but failing in Jenkins. I want to see screenshots for failures, but screenshots are not generating.

```
   Input Text                           ${login_password}    ${password}
capture page screenshot              password.png
click on next                        ${password_next}       ${login_password}
capture page screenshot              next.png
```

It is giving broken image like below.

[image: Screenshot in html report]

I tried with below script to store the screenshots. It is working in Local. But screenshots are generating but not coming in html report if i m doing execution in Jenkins server which is hosted in Linux.

```
   Capture Image
    [Arguments]  ${imagename}
    ${path}=        Catenate   SEPARATOR=       ${EXECDIR}      /      Screenshots     /      ${imagename}  .   png
    capture page screenshot      ${path}
```

Comment: did you tried giving a full path to the screenshots you are taking?
the screenshots are probably on the jenkins machines
but not where it think it is
try specifying a full path such as /tmp/screenshot.png

Comment: Hi Yogev. I tried by passing path as well , still i can't see screenshot. I tried with .png and with out png as well. Getting same issue for both

Comment: Is it possible for you to run a simple 1 test case manually on your linux slave? See if the complexity that Jenkins brings to the table may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved. I am using Robot plugin in Jenkins for results. In Post build configuration till the time i am allowing only log and html report. but now i updated that as to allow .png format files also. So, default it is giving screenshots for failuree.